# spring cloud data flow custom app config to pass enviromental variables

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

i am working on Spring cloud data flow Custom source application which gets data from an rest endpoint . I use Spring cloud data flow and Skipper server to push this custom jar to PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) .This works fine but now i want to pass some custom environmental properties to the application .Below is the  yaml config i used to deploy the jar to the repo . tried passing below it under the env bucket but seems its not getting picked by the application at runtime..Please suggest

```
DB_HOST:host_url
DB_PORT:3306
DB_SCHEMA:test
DB_USER: user
DB_PASS:pwd
```

> application.yml for  pusing the CUSTOM SOURCE to SCDF App Repo

```
---
applications:
  - name: pocclient
    memory: 2G
    instances: 1
    path: ../target/custom-sink-client-0.0.17-SNAPSHOT.jar
    buildpacks:
    - java_buildpack
    env:
      JAVA_VERSION: 1.8.0_+
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
      JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
      DB_HOST:host_url
      DB_PORT:port
      DB_SCHEMA:test
      DB_USER:
      DB_PASS:
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited details in the description, it is unclear what you're trying to do with SCDF and a custom-sink, and likewise, in which platform are you provisioning all the components. You may want to edit the post with more details.

In Cloud Foundry, if you want SCDF to deploy apps with config-server binding automatically, you would want to review the [ref. guide for more information](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_cloud_config_server). The service-instance *must* exist in the same Org/Space, and the service-instance name is expected to be configured in SCDF, so when SCDF deploys apps on your behalf, it will also bind the app with the service-instance automatically.

In Kubernetes, it'd be a similar mechanism; however, you're expected to provide the config-server URI configuration as an environment variable when deploying the desired apps as bare-pods.

Comment: Thanks Sabby. updated the post . i use spring cloud data flow and push the custom jar  to the app repo and deploy to the Cloud Foundry.The service-instance exist in the same Org/Space, and the service-instance name is  configured in SCDF and its binding fine but the  custom properties and not getting passed. I believe the the naming format of the config should be in a specific way for SCDF to understand which app the config belongs to?